# vscode snippets: How to link a position in the snippet to a tabstop?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I want to create a snippet that prints the value of a variable for debugging purposes. this is what I came up with:

```json
{
  "Debug": {
    "prefix": ["db"],
    "body": ["console.log(\"$1 :\", $1)"]
  }
}
```

When I use this snippet cursor goes between the quotes ( | is the cursor position):

```js
console.log("| :",)
```

And after I typed the name of a variable it copies the name to the second parameter:

```js
console.log("name :", name)
```

But I can't use autocompletion in strings. sometimes the variable is an object and auto-completion helps me pick a specific key of the object. I want the cursor to stop in the second parameter so I can use autocompletion:

```js
console.log(" :", |)
```

And whatever I type should be copied inside the double-quotes:

```js
console.log("name :", name)
```

just like the previous example but backward.

How can I do that?

**UPDATE:**
I created an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/142327

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have `Editor > Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions` disabled and

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "other": true,
  "comments": true,
  "strings": true       // the important one here
},
```

In my testing even with those settings it still doesn't work.  That does look like a bug.  It fails even on the simpler case `"\"$1\" $1"`.  So something about being in a string is preventing intellisense despite the settings above.

But there is a *workaround*:

```
"Debug": {
  "prefix": ["db"],
  "body": [
        // select everything you want to surround with quotes
    "console.log(${2:$1 :}, $1)"   // you will get intellisense
  ]
}
```

The `${2:...}` will select the result of tabstop 1 +  `:` and then you can hit `"` to surround that selection with quotes.  You just have to hit one more `tab` then you might be expecting.

[image: intellisense in a string bug]

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the following version:

```
{
  "Debug": {
    "prefix": ["db"],
    "body": ["console.log(\"${2:$1} :\", $1);$0"]
  }
}
```

It starts at $1, but immediately also shows the text for $2, with TAB I can change the text between double quotes but I do not get auto-completion for $1.

I think this should be asked in an issue on the repo. $2 should copy text of $1 after the TAB and $1 should have auto-completion like it does when using

```
{
  "Debug": {
    "prefix": ["db"],
    "body": ["console.log(\"$2 :\", $1);$0"]
  }
}
```